# How do you monitor a read only input in jquery? The .change() method doesnt work as it only works for non read-only inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a line of code like this in my HTML File:

I cannot use a code like this to update the `contractLengthDisplay` because it is read only:

```
$("#contractLengthDisplay").change(function(){
   alert(1);
});
```

Is there an alternative for the .change() method if the input is read only? Thanks!

Comment: If it's read only, how does it change? And what are you listening for?

Comment: How is a readonly input changing? Seems like the point of it being readonly is that it would not. If it is changing due to some other control on the page, couldn't you just hook into that element's change event?

Comment: Changing read only input? Can you let me know how do you change it ?

Comment: There are loads of event listeners. But it depends on how and why you would want to use a certain listener

Comment: @RobM. .. readonly input cannot be changed by user interaction, but its value can always be updated using a script.

Comment: @jagzviruz Yes, I'm aware of that - that is covered in the latter half of my comment. Thank you though :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.trigger("change")` to notify the listener

```js
$("#contractLengthDisplay").on("change", function() { // attach listener
  console.log( this.value );
});


$("#contractLengthDisplay")
    .val("BBBBB")                // change value
    .trigger("change");          // and notify the listener by triggering the event
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<input id="contractLengthDisplay" value="AAAAA" readonly>
```